# Execute html/javascript without browser

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to run html / javascript code belowe without using a browser? The html code creates a png file using a javascript code. (Kendo/jquery)
I would like to show this png file in another application to be able to present nice graphs in that application that way. Suggestions ?

The reason I don't want to use a browser is because I want to display the chart(s) directly in Unisys bis environment (also known as Mapper). However, the environment is not suitable for creating charts, but you can show images. For that reason I try another way.

[example chart.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fwp92.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.330/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.330/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<div id="chart"></div>
<script>
    $("#chart").kendoChart({
        transitions: false,
        series: [{
            type: "column",
            data: [1, 2, 3]
        }, {
            type: "line",
            data: [2, 1, 3]
        }, {
            type: "area",
            data: [3, 1, 2]
        }]
    });

    var chart = $("#chart").getKendoChart();
    chart.exportImage().done(function(data) {
        kendo.saveAs({
            dataURI: data,
            fileName: "chartXXX.png"
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not use a browser though? Electron is an alternative. As well as any image viewer application you expect to be already installed on your user-base's devices.

Comment: The reason I don't want to use a browser is because I want to display the chart(s) directly in Unisys bis environment (also known as Mapper). However, the environment is not suitable for creating charts, but you can show images. For that reason I try another way.